# How to iterate though a XML and sum values based on a condition using python lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have the following XML. I want to go through all the transactions in the transaction list and sum the amounts where category = 'income'. How do i do this using lxml in python ?

```
<TransactionList>
      <Transaction>
        <id>1</id>
        <category>income</category>
        <amount>10</amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <id>2</id>
        <category>income</category>
        <amount>140</amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <id>3</id>
        <category>income</category>
        <amount>0</amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <id>4</id>
        <category>income</category>
        <amount>55</amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <id>5</id>
        <category>exp</category>
        <amount>0</amount>
      </Transaction>
<TransactionList>
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using lxml and it has good xpath support, you could use the [`sum()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-sum) function in an xpath itself...

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = """<TransactionList>
      <Transaction>
        <id>1</id>
        <category>income</category>
        <amount>10</amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <id>2</id>
        <category>income</category>
        <amount>140</amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <id>3</id>
        <category>income</category>
        <amount>0</amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <id>4</id>
        <category>income</category>
        <amount>55</amount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <id>5</id>
        <category>exp</category>
        <amount>0</amount>
      </Transaction>
</TransactionList>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

print(tree.xpath("sum(/TransactionList/Transaction[category='income']/amount)"))
```

This prints:

```
205.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your code into file `transactions.xml` then you can parse the above transaction list with the code below:

```
from lxml import etree

context = etree.parse('transactions.xml').getroot()

total_amount = 0
for transaction in context.findall('Transaction'):
    category = transaction.find('category')
    amount = transaction.find('amount')
    if category and category == 'income' and amount:
        total_amount += int(amount.text)
```